# Inserting a condition inside a FOR loop

Tags: equation-solving, conditional

Some sample data

```
data0 = {{0.00005, -0.99994}, {0.0001, -0.999882}, {0.0004, -0.99953},
         {0.0104, -0.988117}, {0.0204, -1.00472}, {0.0304, -1.01358},
         {0.0404, -1.01729}, {0.0504, -1.01776}};
NICs = Length[data0];
```

and some definitions of derivatives

```
x1 = m3*Sqrt[3];
y1 = 0;
x2 = Sqrt[3]/2*(2*m3 - 1);
y2 = 1/2;
x3 = x2;
y3 = -y2;

r1 = Sqrt[(x - x1)^2 + (y - y1)^2];
r2 = Sqrt[(x - x2)^2 + (y - y2)^2];
r3 = Sqrt[(x - x3)^2 + (y - y3)^2];

Ω = m1/r1 + m2/r2 + m3/r3 + 1/2*(x^2 + y^2);

m2 = m3;
m1 = 1 - 2*m3;

Ωx = D[Ω, x];
Ωy = D[Ω, y];

Ωxx = D[Ωx, x]; 
Ωxy = D[Ωx, y];  
Ωyx = D[Ωy, x];
Ωyy = D[Ωy, y];
```

Now let's setup a FOR loop

```
data = {};
For[j = 1, j <= NICs, j++, 
    m30 = data0[[j, 1]];
    x0 = data0[[j, 2]]; 
    eq = λ^4 + (4 - Ωxx - Ωyy)*λ^2 + Ωxx*Ωyy - Ωxy^2 /. {m3 -> m30, 
         x -> x0, y -> 0};
    sol = Solve[eq == 0, λ];
    AppendTo[data, {m30, x0, k}];
   ]
```

As we can see, inside the new list `data` there is a undefined parameter $k$. The value of this parameter is related with the solutions of the equation `eq==0`. This equation has always four roots. Now, if all four of them are purely imaginary (their real part is equal to zero) then $k = 1$, otherwise $k = -1$.

So my question is: how can I add a condition inside the FOR loop so as to have either $k = 1$ or $k = -1$  in `data`, according to the particular initial conditions?

The new list should be as follows

```
data = {{0.00005, -0.99994, 1}, {0.0001, -0.999882, 1}, 
        {0.0004, -0.9995295, 1}, {0.0104, -0.9881174, -1},  
        {0.0204, -1.0047199, -1}, {0.0304, -1.0135774, -1}, 
        {0.0404, -1.0172852, -1}, {0.0504, -1.0177593, -1}}
```

**EDIT**

Following @george2079 suggestion we can define $k$ as

```
k = If[Re[λ /. sol[[1]]] == 0 && Re[λ /. sol[[2]]] == 0 && 
       Re[λ /. sol[[3]]] == 0 && Re[λ /. sol[[4]]] == 0, 1, -1];
```

Is there any other, more elegant solution? 
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: `k=If[condition,1,-1]`

Comment: @george2079 Is there a more elegant way of writing `k = If[Re[λ /. sol[[1]]] == 0 && Re[λ /. sol[[2]]] == 0 && 
    Re[λ /. sol[[3]]] == 0 && Re[λ /. sol[[4]]] == 0, 1, -1];`?

Comment: you can use `AllTrue` or `VectorQ`

Comment: a bit aside but i think you can get that result more elegantly if you write the expression in terms of `I lambda` and check the discriminant.

Comment: @george2079 Could you post a quick answer so as to accept it? Perhaps showing the use of `VectorQ`...

Comment: @george2079 I think one could look at it merely as a quadratic equation in `u == λ^2` and compare something like `0 < b && 0 < 4 a c < b^2`, where `a = 1`, etc.  Whether `<` or `<=` depends on how one feels about `0` as a pure imaginary number.

Comment: my thought was write `lambda = I z` and use `b^2-4 a c` to show that `z` is real, but since the equation is really fourth order that only tells us if `z^2` is real. You also need to show `z^2>0` so you may as well just use `Solve`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `VectorQ`  :

```
sol = \[Lambda] /. Solve[eq == 0, \[Lambda]];
k = If[VectorQ[sol, Chop[Re[#] == 0] &], 1, -1];
AppendTo[data, {m30, x0, k}];
```

I added `Chop` in case some values might be machine precision small but not quite exactly zero.

note you really should use `Map` here instead of `For`, it will be much faster and cleaner.

```
data = (
     m30 = #[[1]];
     x0 = #[[2]];
     eq = \[Lambda]^4 + (4 - \[CapitalOmega]xx - \[CapitalOmega]yy)*\
     \[Lambda]^2 + \[CapitalOmega]xx*\[CapitalOmega]yy - \
     \[CapitalOmega]xy^2 /. {m3 -> m30, x -> x0, y -> 0};
     sol = \[Lambda] /. Solve[eq == 0, \[Lambda]];
     k = If[VectorQ[sol, Chop[Re[#] == 0] &], 1, -1];
     {m30, x0, k}) & /@ data0;
```

Note this can be written even more compactly but I left it looking like your `For` construct to illustrate `Map`

```
eq = \[Lambda]^4 + (4 - \[CapitalOmega]xx - \[CapitalOmega]yy)*\
      \[Lambda]^2 + \[CapitalOmega]xx*\[CapitalOmega]yy - \
       \[CapitalOmega]xy^2;
data =
  {#[[1]], #[[2]],
     If[VectorQ[\[Lambda] /.
        Solve[(eq /.
            {m3 -> #[[1]], x -> #[[2]], y -> 0}) == 0, \[Lambda]],
       Chop[Re[#] == 0] &], 1, -1]} & /@ data0;
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with `Map`. How can `Map` replace the existing `For` loop?

Comment: You are right! When the original `data0` list contains about 10000 initial conditions the compact forms are much more faster then the traditional `For` loop! Many thanks again!